# eclipse weblogic outbound calls

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic, network-monitoring

In Eclipse we have configured weblogic server and we have deployed the java application. How to trace all the call with request and reponse made by the weblogic server like wireshark. since my company wont allow the wireshark to install, I need alternative for wireshark.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can trace network traffic on your VMs in Azure by using Packet Capture, which his a feature provided by a service called Network Watcher. Packet Captures created by Network Watcher can be saved to your blob storage account or locally on the VM, and the tool works for Windows and Linux.

[Packet Capture Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/network-watcher-packet-capture-overview)

[Network Watcher Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/network-watcher-monitoring-overview)